# If $f(x,y)=x^3 -3x(1+y^2)$, and $D=\left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \right \}$, how to show that $f$ has a minimum and maximum on D?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

My first thoughts would be to show that $f$ is uniformly continues on $D$ and show that $D$ is a compact. The problem is that I have difficulties showing both of these two statements. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You don't need to verify that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$ (though it does turn out to be). All you need is continuity, and $f$ is obviously continuous because it's a polynomial. $D$ is compact because it's closed and bounded. You can then invoke the extreme value theorem: a continuous real-valued function on a compact set attains a minimum and maximum.

Comment: Note that $D$ is compact, so any continuous function has a $\max,\min$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous because sums and products of continuous functions are continuous. The set $D$ is compact because it is closed and bounded.

It is closed because $D=g^{-1}((-\infty,1])$, where $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, the function $g$ is continuous and $(-\infty,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. It is bounded because it is contained in $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$.

So the function certainly has maximum and minimum in $D$.